# Input array (resulted from boolean operation) considered valid in formula window but ignored in cell evaluation (when dynamic arrays not supported)

Tags: .net, excel, vba

If I type numbers 1,2,3,4,5 in range A1-A5 and then type this formula in B1 cell
:`=COUNT(2*(A1:A5=6))`, the value 1 is returned (instead of 5, the number of array members).
[image].

But if I open the formula window, I can see that the result is indeed 5 and also *argument1* is consindered as an array:
[image]

Furthermore in debugging VBA or .NET (EXCEL-DNA) I can confirm that in the first case *argument1* is considered as integer, while when opening formula window, debugger catches function and shows that argument 1 is an array with 5 members.

How can I use arrays as an input and make i.e. `=COUNT(2*(A1:A5=3))` return 5 in a cell?

Comment: Probably you have an older version of Excel and need to confirm this **array-formula** with `ctrl+shift+enter` instead of just `enter`

Comment: If you want to avoid using Ctrl+Shift+Enter as suggested by @BenRosenfeld then you can write it like ```=COUNT(INDEX(2*(A1:A5=3),0))```

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to avoid  ctrl+shift+enter because needed to use it in multiple cells. The index trick did my job! Also, yes my excel edition does not support dynamic arrays.

Comment: Cristian you could turn it to answer to accept it...